Google Apps Script: Issues with Preserving Bullet Icons and Resetting Numbering When Copying List Items form one doc to other google document
I'm working with Google Apps Script to insert/copy text from one Google Document into another. These text can include various types of content, including bullet and numbered lists. However, I'm encountering two issues:

When inserting a bullet list, all bullet icons are not preserved, resulting in a plain list without the intended bullet styling.
When inserting a numbered list, the numbering continues from the last number, rather than restarting from 1. For example, if I insert a text with a list numbered from 1 to 5, and then insert it again, it continues numbering from 6 instead of restarting from 1.

Original document
After Insert
Bellow is my code and I have attached screenshots of original document and when inserting/copying that into new document.
I am expecting that when inserting the clause/text it should preserve as it is with original list formatting which is there in original document shared in screenshots.
How to Use:

Create a new Google Apps Script project and paste the above code.
Save and authorize the script.
Run the script in any Google Document to test it out. The script will add a "Clause Manager" menu from which you can insert clauses by providing a Document ID.

This script should work as an add-on that you can use directly in any Google Document.
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Clause Manager')
    .addItem('Insert Clause', 'insertClause')
    .addToUi();
}

function insertClause() {
  const ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  const response = ui.prompt('Enter the Clause Document ID:');
  
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    const clauseId = response.getResponseText();
    const document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    const cursor = document.getCursor();

    if (!cursor) {
      ui.alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
      return;
    }

    const element = cursor.getElement();
    insertClauseInsideDocumentBody(document, element, clauseId, 'ClauseName');
  }
}

function insertClauseInsideDocumentBody(document, element, clauseId, clauseName) {
  try {
    const documentBody = document.getBody();
    let index = documentBody.getChildIndex(element);

    const clauseDocument = DocumentApp.openById(clauseId);
    const clauseBody = clauseDocument.getBody();

    if (clauseBody.getNumChildren() === 0) {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('The clause document is empty.');
      return;
    }

    const clauseElements = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < clauseBody.getNumChildren(); i++) {
      const child = clauseBody.getChild(i);
      const childContent = child.copy();
      let clauseElement;

      switch (child.getType()) {
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH: {
          const paraElement = documentBody.insertParagraph(index, childContent);
          clauseElement = paraElement;
          index++;
          break;
        }
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM: {
          const listElement = documentBody.insertListItem(index, childContent);
          listElement.setAttributes(child.getAttributes());
          clauseElement = listElement;
          index++;
          break;
        }
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE: {
          const tableElement = documentBody.insertTable(index, childContent);
          clauseElement = tableElement;
          index++;
          break;
        }
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE: {
          const imageElement = documentBody.insertImage(index, childContent);
          clauseElement = imageElement;
          index++;
          break;
        }
        default:
          clauseElement = null;
          break;
      }

      if (clauseElement) {
        clauseElements.push(clauseElement);
      }
    }

    const rangeBuilder = document.newRange();
    rangeBuilder.addElementsBetween(clauseElements[0].editAsText(), 1, clauseElements[clauseElements.length - 1].editAsText(), clauseElements[clauseElements.length - 1].editAsText().getText().length - 1);
    document.addNamedRange(clauseName, rangeBuilder.build());
    
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Clause inserted successfully.');
    
  } catch (error) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('An error occurred: ' + error.message);
  }
}


